# Pip3 - Python 3.8.9 - mac M1 - No import is working properly from my scripts

Tags: python, macos, pip, apple-m1, pypi

So I'm struggling with what will be, I'm sure, an easy fix: No matter what I import in my Python scripts, I always get the error message

```
from flask import Flask;
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask'
```

Replace "flask" here by any other module (tried "psycopg2"), nothing gets imported. I believe that it has something to do with my shell somehow but I'm not sure where the problem comes from and especially, how to fix it.

Here's more information about my config:

- Apple M1 Max
- **macOS**: 12.5 (21G72) - Monterey
- **Terminal**: iTerm2 - Build 3.4.16
- Using [OhMyZsh](https://ohmyz.sh/)
- **Pyhton**: V Python 3.8.9
- **pip3**: V pip 22.1.2

Pip list:

```
Package          Version
---------------- -------
click            8.1.3
Flask            2.1.3
Flask-SQLAlchemy 2.5.1
itsdangerous     2.1.2
Jinja2           3.1.2
MarkupSafe       2.1.1
pip              22.1.2
psycopg2         2.9.3
psycopg2-binary  2.9.3
setuptools       58.1.0
SQLAlchemy       1.4.39
Werkzeug         2.2.0
```

any ideas?

EDIT:

- where python: python: aliased to /usr/bin/python3
- where python3:

  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
  /opt/homebrew/bin/python3
  /usr/local/bin/python3
  /usr/bin/python3
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3
  /opt/homebrew/bin/python3
- where pip

  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/pip
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/pip
- where pip3

  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/pip3
  /opt/homebrew/bin/pip3
  /usr/local/bin/pip3
  /usr/bin/pip3
  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/pip3
  /opt/homebrew/bin/pip3

EDIT2:

Sys code:

```
➜  ~ python3
Python 3.10.5 (v3.10.5:f377153967, Jun  6 2022, 12:36:10) [Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.30)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys; print(sys.path)
['', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python310.zip', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload', '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages']
```

pip show psycopg2:

```
➜  ~ pip show psycopg2
Name: psycopg2
Version: 2.9.3
Summary: psycopg2 - Python-PostgreSQL Database Adapter
Home-page: https://psycopg.org/
Author: Federico Di Gregorio
Author-email: fog@initd.org
License: LGPL with exceptions
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by:
```

EDIT 3: profiles and shell related files.

~ folder:
1  staff    150 Jun 29 18:57 .bash_profile
1  staff    131 May 30 16:47 .bashrc
22  staff    704 May 30 13:32 .oh-my-zsh
1  staff    292 Jun 29 18:32 .zprofile
1  staff    126 Jun 17 10:19 .zprofile.pysave
1  staff  18097 Jul 28 09:53 .zsh_history
7  staff    224 Jul 13 13:38 .zsh_sessions
1  staff   4163 Jul 21 11:39 .zshrc

cat bash_profile:

```
source ~/.bashrc
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
export PYTHONPATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/python"
```

cat .zprofile

```
export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"

# Setting PATH for Python 3.10
# The original version is saved in .zprofile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
```

cat .zshrc

```
# If you come from bash you might have to change your $PATH.
# export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

# Path to your oh-my-zsh installation.
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

# Set name of the theme to load --- if set to "random", it will
# load a random theme each time oh-my-zsh is loaded, in which case,
# to know which specific one was loaded, run: echo $RANDOM_THEME
# See https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes
ZSH_THEME="robbyrussell"

# Set list of themes to pick from when loading at random
# Setting this variable when ZSH_THEME=random will cause zsh to load
# a theme from this variable instead of looking in $ZSH/themes/
# If set to an empty array, this variable will have no effect.
# ZSH_THEME_RANDOM_CANDIDATES=( "robbyrussell" "agnoster" )

# Uncomment the following line to use case-sensitive completion.
# CASE_SENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to use hyphen-insensitive completion.
# Case-sensitive completion must be off. _ and - will be interchangeable.
# HYPHEN_INSENSITIVE="true"

# Uncomment one of the following lines to change the auto-update behavior
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode disabled  # disable automatic updates
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode auto      # update automatically without asking
# zstyle ':omz:update' mode reminder  # just remind me to update when it's time

# Uncomment the following line to change how often to auto-update (in days).
# zstyle ':omz:update' frequency 13

# Uncomment the following line if pasting URLs and other text is messed up.
# DISABLE_MAGIC_FUNCTIONS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable colors in ls.
# DISABLE_LS_COLORS="true"

# Uncomment the following line to disable auto-setting terminal title.
# DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"

# Uncomment the following line to enable command auto-correction.
# ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

# Uncomment the following line to display red dots whilst waiting for completion.
# You can also set it to another string to have that shown instead of the default red dots.
# e.g. COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="%F{yellow}waiting...%f"
# Caution: this setting can cause issues with multiline prompts in zsh < 5.7.1 (see #5765)
# COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to disable marking untracked files
# under VCS as dirty. This makes repository status check for large repositories
# much, much faster.
# DISABLE_UNTRACKED_FILES_DIRTY="true"

# Uncomment the following line if you want to change the command execution time
# stamp shown in the history command output.
# You can set one of the optional three formats:
# "mm/dd/yyyy"|"dd.mm.yyyy"|"yyyy-mm-dd"
# or set a custom format using the strftime function format specifications,
# see 'man strftime' for details.
# HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

# Would you like to use another custom folder than $ZSH/custom?
# ZSH_CUSTOM=/path/to/new-custom-folder

# Which plugins would you like to load?
# Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
# Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
# Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
# Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
plugins=(git)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
A
# User configuration

# export MANPATH="/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"

# You may need to manually set your language environment
# export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

# Preferred editor for local and remote sessions
# if [[ -n $SSH_CONNECTION ]]; then
#   export EDITOR='vim'
# else
#   export EDITOR='mvim'
# fi

# Compilation flags
# export ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64"

# Set personal aliases, overriding those provided by oh-my-zsh libs,
# plugins, and themes. Aliases can be placed here, though oh-my-zsh
# users are encouraged to define aliases within the ZSH_CUSTOM folder.
# For a full list of active aliases, run `alias`.
#
# Example aliases
# alias zshconfig="mate ~/.zshrc"
# alias ohmyzsh="mate ~/.oh-my-zsh"
alias python=/usr/bin/python3
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/bin:$PATH"
export LIBRARY_PATH=$LIBRARY_PATH:/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/lib/
export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/lib"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/libpq/include"
```

Comment: What does pip3 list show?

Comment: The same packages. As a matter of fact, no matter if I do `$pip list` or `$pip3 list` it returns the same list.

Comment: Could you also share the outputs of ```where python```, ```where python3```, ```where pip``` and ```where pip3```?

Comment: Done in the question (Edited)

Comment: Show us the output of this code: `import sys; print(sys.path)`

Comment: And also this command: `pip show psycopg2 `

Comment: The sys.path output includes `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages`, which is exactly where pip says psycopg2 is installed, so I don't understand why that import is not working...

Comment: No idea either. I'm now thinking that it might have to do with the shell I'm using and that maybe I messed things up with the profiles? I'm adding an EDIT with the profiles and shell related files I got.

Comment: Why is there Python 3.8.9 in the question title and config overview, but 3.10 in all the paths listed and the Python prompt shown?

Comment: Note that `python` is `/usr/bin/python3`, while `python3` is `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin/python3`, the Homebrew installed Python. That's likely where you go wrong: you've installed Python 3.10 with Homebrew, and are now running the wrong `pip3` for `python`: the latter is the system (3.8.9) Python, but `pip3` is the Homebrew (3.10) one.

Comment: Just install stuff with `python -m pip`, and use that same `python` to run things, and you should be fine. In this specific case, you can use `python3.10`, since you clearly intended to use that, by installing it with Homebrew.

Comment: Yeyy!! I knew it was another one of my stupid f***-ups! Thanks! @9769953. If you want to publish your answer so that I can select it as the solution that'd be great! Thanks!

Comment: Oddly enough, I've answered similar questions a dozen times over the past years (so you're not the only one doing this), but probably always in a comment: I can't find a proper answer to your question amongst my own answers, and I'm too lazy for an extensive StackOverflow search for a duplicate (of which there will also be a dozen). So I will write an answer here, but it may be a bit broader than specifically for your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summary: use

```
python -m pip install <packages>
```

to guarantee that `python` can find the installed packages.

---

This is a problem that comes up often when there are multiple Python installations on the same system. For example, there may be a default (system) Python, and one that a user themselves has installed, because that one is more recent (or they need a specific version; like, Guido forbid, Python 2, because they have to run an old Python script or use an old Python package).

As a result, and at times with the help of some aliasing, you may end up in a situation where `python` refers to the system Python, as here: `/usr/bin/python`. While e.g. `python3` may refer to the user installed Python, as here `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`. That is still fine, because these are different commands.

Enter `pip`, the Python package manager: it may be installed for only one of the multiple Python versions, or it may be installed for all of them, but each time with a different name. As a result, `pip` may install packages for `/usr/bin/python`, or it may install packages for e.g. `/opt/homebrew/bin/python3`. Depending on the setup (and on the use of `sudo`, but more on that below), these packages may end up in different places. And if the two Python versions are different enough, the installed packages will not be compatible, and will also be installed in different subdirectories of the package installation directory (on Linux, it would go in `$HOME/.local/lib/pythonx.y`, with `x.y` indicating the different versions. On macOS, somewhere in `$HOME/Library`. Note that this applies to a user, i.e. local, installation, without `sudo`).

To complicate things, the python 2-to-3 transition resulted in systems naming executables specifically `python3` or `pip3`, while `python` would still be Python 2. Now that most Python 2 (system) scripts have been ported to Python 3, that habit has worn off, Python 2 was ditched, and `python` now refers to Python 3. But you may still be caught in the middle of this, and some names remain. Confusing! (Python 3 should just have been named completely different, for example, `monty`. That would have avoided a lot of confusion.)

So if you're lucky, everything works. If you're unlucky, the Pip installation installed for the wrong Python, and it's a long search which Python to use (or how to re-install the packages for the correct Python).

`python`, the executable, does have the option to run a package as a script (to phrase it simply): `python -m <package>` will do that. That will guarantee that the package/script uses that `python` executable. Pip is one of those packages that can do that (in fact, the `pip` or `pip3` script is a short wrapper around that functionality).

So using `python -m pip install <package>` guarantees that a package installed by pip, will be found by `python` as well. No messing with incompatible `python` and `pip` executables.

---

I don't recommend the use of `sudo` on a single user system. It may mess up the system, because plenty of people don't know the details of their system. `sudo` should preferably only be used by system administrators to install software for other users on the system.

What about Pip? Pip has an option, `--user`, that will install packages in a directory that Python will automatically find, but is user related, in the user's home directory. In fact, recent versions of Pip will automatically use that directory if they find they can't install packages in the normal (system) place. There'll be a note in the output, and then pip implicitly installs with the `--user` option. This is good in 90% (or more) of the cases, since this is very likely the intention of the person using Pip, and not too many people know about `--user`.

---

For (properly installed and activated) virtual environment, this problem doesn't exist. `python` and `pip` are unique within that virtual environment. This includes a Conda environment.

And, in fact, the built-in virtual environment creation for Python is another example of a runnable module:

```
python -m venv <name>
```

This also guarantees that your virtual environment uses (a copy of) that specific `python` executable. If you had wanted a virtual environment with another Python version, use e.g.

```
python3.8 -m venv <name>
```

(don't forget to activate the relevant v-env afterwards!).
When not activated, you'll be using the default `python`, but when activated, `python3.8`. Easy switching!

This doesn't work for all `python` executables: Python 2 doesn't have the `venv` package, and `python` executables on some systems are very barebones, and no `venv` package will exist. Often, that can be amended (if you are using the system Python), by installing the relevant package: `sudo apt install python-venv` or something similar(*). (Another case where it's debatable if `sudo` should actually be used on a single user system, but harder to avoid.)

---

Note that to a point, Python versions are always distinguishable by using the major.minor version added to the `python` executable. So, when done well, a system can have `python2.7, python3.6, python3.7, python3.8, python3.9 and python3.10` all work independently from each other.

I actually use this to occasionally switch and test versions with [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv). Just be careful that you don't open another can of worms if you're not used to managing Python versions.

(*) In my option, it's a shame that some systems separate pip and venv from the default Python package, and/or don't install these by default. Installing these by default requires very little extra disk space, and provide a huge convenience. If you want a barebones systems, it should be a simple uninstall of system packages like python-pip and python-venv, instead of the other way around.

---

Caveat: while this technically applies everywhere, IDEs such as Visual Studio Code may still cause new people problems, because they have both a terminal, people may use another terminal, and then there is the configuration/settings themselves, where you can specify a Python interpreter (and sometimes a Pip executable as well).

The above solution should work fine on a command line by itself. Within an IDE, I can't guarantee this, but do check your settings for both Python and Pip, and beware of virtual environments set up (automatically) by your IDE, which may make things even worse, since the v-env will need to be activated before installing packages (and then again in a next session, when running Python).

Comment: This is a horribly long answer. But I've answered this problem (always with the same solution, see at the top of this answer) too many times in a comment. I couldn't be bothered with finding a duplicate, so instead I took a deep breath and wrote down what I know about Python and Pip installation confusing.

Comment: It's too long: corrections, amendments, shortening suggestions etc etc are welcome. Either in a comment or by a direct edit. I have not yet made this a community wiki, but if this becomes popular enough somehow (and doesn't get closed as a duplicate, that may be a good thing to do).

Comment: Hey @9769953! That's a really cool answer that helps wrap our mind around the problem I experienced. Now that you settled this, I'm gonna try to find out how to clean my system.

Comment: @MartinCarre That may prove to be an interesting challenge, since I've seen Homebrew paths on your system, but also VSC (which may or may not install yet another Python version; I don't know what it can or will do), and then there are things like `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/bin`, which I have no idea of where these come from (perhaps from VCS; or from the www.python.org installer?). I see at least 3 Python versions on your system: /usr/bin/python3, the Homebrew one, and whatever lurks in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/...` . [tbc]

Comment: @MartinCarre [cont.] Oh, and there is `/usr/local/bin/python3` (from `where python3`), with unknown origin, so that makes 4 Python versions. Which may or may not be the same version (i.e., with compatible packages & libraries), and may or may not be aliased (symbolic links).